# Invalid number comes when accessing member structures

Tags: c, structure

I am new to c language. I add the structure members(int dd) to file(file.txt) and now am trying to read that file to access structure members(Day.dd). But when I **add 5**  to a variable through scanf() function and compile that file and run, **I did not get (Day = 5)**. **I got Day =   1325715504**

```
My code is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct DailyCost
{
    int dd;

} Day;
FILE *fp;
void add_dailycost();
void display();
void mainmenue();
int main()
{

    int j;
    fp = fopen("/home/mohit/projects/c/gedit_Dailyost/TextFiles/fileb.txt", "w+");
    rewind(fp);
    mainmenue();
    return 0;
}
void mainmenue()
{
    struct DailyCost day1;
    int j;
    printf("Enter 1 to add dailycost and enter 2 display dailycost.");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    switch (j)
    {
    case 1:
        add_dailycost(day1);
        break;
    case 2:
        display(day1);
        break;
    }
}
void add_dailycost(struct DailyCost Day)
{
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    }
    int j;
    printf("Enter Day = ");
    scanf("%d", &Day.dd);
    fwrite(&Day, sizeof(struct DailyCost), 1, fp);
    printf("If menmenue press 1 and exit press 0 = ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    if (j == 1)
    {
        mainmenue();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThank you");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(0);
    }
}
void display(struct DailyCost Day)
{
    fread(&Day, sizeof(struct DailyCost), 1, fp);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("Day =   %d\n", Day.dd);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Please suggest what I had done wrong to code a program. And how to fix this problem, by taking my code.

Comment: You are passing the struct by value to the functions, that means if you modify the structure fields in the function, you will modify a copy, not the original. You need to use a pointer to the original as function argument.

Comment: In line with the first comment, don't pass any argument to the function, add_dailycost, at all as your Day object is visible to the function.

Comment: @ Klaus Gütter  - Please suggest in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Klaus Gütter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142950/klaus-g%C3%BCtter) use call by reference, to make changes to original object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct DailyCost
{
    int dd;

} Day;
FILE *fp;
void add_dailycost();
void display();
void mainmenue();
int main()
{

    int j;
    fp = fopen("/home/mohit/projects/c/gedit_Dailyost/TextFiles/fileb.txt", "w+");
    rewind(fp);
    mainmenue();
    return 0;
}
void mainmenue()
{
    struct DailyCost day1;
    int j;
    printf("Enter 1 to add dailycost and enter 2 display dailycost.");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    switch (j)
    {
    case 1:
        add_dailycost(&day1);
        break;
    case 2:
        display(&day1);
        break;
    }
}
void add_dailycost(struct DailyCost* Day) /*if you pass simply 
  struct DailyCost , all the contents of original objects will be copied 
  into a new memory area, to be used in this function and will be 
  destroyed when this function exits. */
/* if you pass just the address of your object,you are working on 
   the same memory area as you passed from,in this case from mainmenue. */
{
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    }
    int j;
    printf("Enter Day = ");
    scanf("%d", &Day->dd);
    fwrite(Day, sizeof(struct DailyCost), 1, fp);
    printf("If menmenue press 1 and exit press 0 = ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    if (j == 1)
    {
        mainmenue();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThank you");
        fclose(fp);
        exit(0);
    }
}
void display(struct DailyCost* Day) /* passing the object instead 
  of reference would also work here. But just for the display 
  purpose, you need not to unnecessarily create a new memory. */
{
    fread(Day, sizeof(struct DailyCost), 1, fp);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("Day =   %d\n", Day->dd);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Read about **call by value** and **call by reference**, and **passing struct as argument** in the internet, if you are not clear yet.